# Grafana import shared file

Tags: grafana

In Grafana 10.2.2 I need to import shared file via username, password and file location. That shared file contain some images. I think I can use canvas or text as visualization.

How can import a shared file via username, password and location

Comment: By shared file do you mean SMB share?

Comment: Yes like SMB share